# Interval $(-\infty,a)$ in sigma-algebra of $\{(a,b):a,b\in\mathbb{Q}\}$

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I want to show that for $x\in\mathbb{R}$

> $$(-\infty,x)\subset\sigma(\{(a,b):a,b\in\mathbb{Q}\})$$

So I want to write it as a combination of unions and complements of intervals $(a,b)$.
Since $x\in\mathbb{R}$, there is a Cauchy sequence $(x_n)$ in $\mathbb{Q}$. However I cannot simply take
$$(-\infty,x)=\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(-n,x_n)$$
since I don't know what $(x_n)$ looks like. I.e. How do I make a monotonic increasing sequence that converges to $x$?

Comment: There is a lemma commonly used in the proof of the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem that states that every real sequence has a monotonic subsequence.

Comment: @cronos2 I believe that this is not useful because we need a monotonic sequence with a specified direction (namely, increasing)

Comment: I don't see why. If $\{y_n\} \subset \{x_n\} \to x$ is already increasing then we're good to go, otherwise consider $y'_n = x - (y_n - x) \to x$

Comment: True! I was just noting that this is you saying, not Bolzano-Wiestrass :) Sorry for the pedantry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it is easy to see that $(-\infty,q)$ is in the sigma algebra for rational $q$.
Since the rational numbers are countable, you can do something like
$$
 (-\infty,x)=\bigcup_{q<x, q\in\mathbb Q} (-\infty,q)
$$

Comment: Very nice solution, thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use just the fact that "there is a Cauchy sequence", then indeed you're going to have a hard time. It's much easier if instead you *construct*  that sequence yourself. Tip: do something like $\pi = \mbox{limit of $3; 3.1; 3.14; \ldots$}$